# Optimización de Código php para que sea más ligero

Tags: php

Yo no se mucho de php y me gustaría optimizar este código a ser lo más ligero posible, no es mucho código, pero los recursos que posea son bastante escasos, así que considero oportuno que me alumbren un poco con sus conocimientos ya que yo provengo del mundo de JavaScript.

```
<?php

require_once 'database/config.php';

if(!empty($_POST)) {

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last = $_POST['last'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $passHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(username, name, last, email, password) VALUES (:username, :name, :last, :email, :password)";

  $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

  $result = $query->execute([
    'username' => $username,
    'name' => $name,
    'last' => $last,
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
  ]);
}

?>
```

Comment: mas ligero en que sentido? hay una consulta y nada mas.. que te gustaria aligerar?

Comment: Me gustaría que la forma de escritura sea más corta de ser posible.

Comment: eso no optimiza nada. y realmente dudo que se pueda escribir mas corto que eso...

Comment: Sólo un detalle: **Nunca se guarda un pasword plano**, lo estás haciendo y no haces nada con el hash que sería lo que debes guardar para validarlo.

Comment: el if antes del require, del resto se encarga el optimizador.  $result va a ser true si todo bien o false si hubo error. tal vez un  `if (empty($_POST['username'])) exit();` al principio libera recursos

Comment: Es verdad @aloMalbarez, ahora que me doy cuenta es así, porque así si no existe un _POST no se cargará la base de datos, no hay motivo. Gracias de verdad. Lo que no comprendo es ese exit() que colocas antes de terminar la sentencia, recuerda que no soy muy diestro en php.

Comment: exit() simplemente termina el script y llama los destructores de los objetos/clases en memoria, no procesa mas de ahi

Comment: @aloMalbarez entonces el exit lo coloco antes del cierre del php?

Comment: no sería necesario, lo puse como ejemplo de que si no hay un campo post esencial simplemente termine el script ahi (al principio)

Comment: falla silenciosamente, si queres retornar un código de error o algun mensaje vale el if else normal

Comment: @aloMalbarez muchas gracias. Esa señalacion que hizo quevedo sobre guardar password plano se que no debe ser. ¿Cómo puedo completar esa parte del código? Ya que si guardo el password encriptado entonces tendria que desencriptarlo antes de hacer una peticion a la hora de consultar ese dato. No se si me di a entender.

Comment: hm nope, lo que guardas es un hash y al recibir un password para login lo hasheas y comparas los hashes: no necesitas saber la clave, necesitas saber si la clave que te dan es la misma que te dieron al darse de alta

Comment: @aloMalbarez muchas gracias hermano, que tengas buenas noches.

Comment: en el primer insert (registro) guardas el passhash, al hacer un login haces un passhash de la clave que te dan  y lo comparas con lo que hay en la db

Comment: Se trata de hacer el trabajo dos veces para luego comparar el resultado, en este caso el hash.

Comment: Particularmente no estoy de acuerdo con evaluar en PHP si el POST está vacío, es algo que debes hacer en el cliente, no en el servidor. O sea, controlar por medio de Javascript, que el formulario no se envía vacío. En PHP el control debe estar enfocado directamente a cada campo: puedes usar un temario para almacenar cada valor o `NULL` o cadena vacía o `0` según el caso, luego paras el insert si alguna de las columnas obligatorias es nula, o lo lanzas si todo está bien en ese sentido. Como ya tienes las variables puedes pasar un array con ellas al `execute`, evitando usar POST de nuevo.

Comment: @A.Cedano los datos deben verificarse tanto en el cliente como en el servidor. No podes saber quien hizo la llamada ni desde donde. Por lo tanto se debe suponer siempre que los datos vienen mal.

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón: *No podes saber quien hizo la llamada ni desde donde*  ... sin embargo, yo no evaluaría si el POST está vacío... me centraría en evaluar las variables esenciales una vez obtenido cada dato mediante un ternario en el que asignaría `NULL` o `0`o `''` a las variables vacías. Mi evaluación sería esta: `if ($varEsencial1 && $varEsencial2 && $varEsencialN){ //conecto y ejecuto}else{//mensaje de que faltan datos}`

Comment: Tambien es valido eso.. entiendo tu punto y lo comparto...